# Python3 proxies http or https?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i did **Python** file that use proxies :

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://{}:{}".format(proxy, port)
}
auth = HTTPProxyAuth(user, passwd)
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = proxies
session.auth = auth

response = session.get(link)
```

i'm curious , when i use http proxy the ssl certificated websites such as https://stackoverflow.com/
know my location .

**so should i only use https proxies or there is something i do wrongly ?**

Comment: If your *link* is https:// then your proxy setup will do nothing

Comment: should i use https_proxy ? can you provide me full info about this topic ?

Answer (score 1):

The proxies dictionary requires entries for all of the protocols you're interested in.

For example:

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://{}:{}".format(proxy, port),
    "https": "https://{}:{}".format(proxy, port)
}
```

Would work if you want to use the same proxy for both http and https

Comment: It's likely the proxy speaks only http, so both links could be the same. Depends on the proxy, of course.

Comment: thanks for response just simple thing i need to know should i speak with https website with https_proxy only ?